# Is the answer sheet wrong? Maximum and minimum value of this $2\sin^3x + \frac 34 \sin 2x + \frac 92 \cos 2x - 9\cos x - \frac 32 x + 6 $

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

I was asked to find maximum and minimum value of this $$2\sin^3x + \frac 34 \sin 2x + \frac 92 \cos 2x - 9\cos x - \frac 32 x + 6 $$ also $$0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$ and local extremum at $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$. The answer was maximum at $0$ and minimum at $\frac{\pi}{3}$. I used calculator but i found that at $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$ it yields -94.151 and when $x= \frac{\pi}{2}$ it yields -137.5

Is the answer sheet wrong?

Comment: $f(\frac{\pi}{2})\neq -137.5$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{3})\neq -94.151$

Comment: How to calculate it?

Comment: I think you have an error in your calculations. The expression is definitely bigger than
$$
g(x) = -2-\frac{3}{4}-\frac{9}{2} -9 -\frac{3}{2}x +6 = \frac{-41}{4} - \frac{3}{2}x
$$
That's a (very conservative!) lower limit for the function. Therefore, $f(\frac{\pi}{2}) > g(\frac{\pi}{2}) \approx -12.606$

Comment: Near end we have $-\frac 32 x$, So when $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $-\frac 34 . 3.14 $ not $-\frac 34 90 $?

Comment: you must use $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for the $-\frac{3}{2}x$ term

Comment: we have $-\frac 34 . 3.14 $ not $-\frac 34 90 $?

Comment: Yes because $\frac{\pi}{2}\neq 90$. Notice that $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Thanks.. no wonder it was wrong

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x)=2\sin^3x + \frac 34 \sin 2x + \frac 92 \cos 2x - 9\cos x - \frac 32 x + 6 .$$
Thus, $$f'(x)=6\sin^2x\cos{x}+\frac{3}{2}\cos2x-9\sin2x+9\sin{x}-\frac{3}{2}=$$
$$=6\cos{x}-6\cos^3x+3\cos^2x-3-18\sin{x}\cos{x}+9\sin{x}=$$
$$=3(2\cos{x}-1)-3\cos^2x(2\cos{x}-1)-9\sin{x}(2\cos{x}-1)=$$
$$=3(2\cos{x}-1)(\sin^2x-3\sin{x})=3(1-2\cos{x})(3-\sin{x})\sin{x}.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 1):

[WolframAlpha confirms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum+2sin%5E3x+%2B+3%2F4+sin+2x+%2B+9%2F2+cos+2x+-+9cos+x+-+3%2F2+x+%2B+6+for+0%3Cx%3Cpi%2F2) that the minimum is at $x=\frac\pi3$.

We can see from the graph in that link that $x=0$ is the maximum as this is where the turning point is (although WolframAlpha [struggles to identify this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum+2sin%5E3x+%2B+3%2F4+sin+2x+%2B+9%2F2+cos+2x+-+9cos+x+-+3%2F2+x+%2B+6+for+0%3Cx%3Cpi%2F2))

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-Your calculations are wrong. You have correctly being $f$ the function
$$f\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)\approx -0.37223916\\f\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\approx 1.14380550\\f(0)=1.5$$

Answer (score 1):

Computing the derivative of $$f(x)=2\sin^3(x) + \frac 34 \sin (2x) + \frac 92 \cos (2x) - 9\cos (x) - \frac 32 x + 6$$ and using the tangent half-angle substitution, you wold end with
$$f'(t)=\frac{6 t \left(3 t^2-1\right) (3 t^2-2t+3)}{\left(1+t^2\right)^3}$$ and notice that $\frac{6  (3 t^2-2t+3)}{\left(1+t^2\right)^3} >0 \quad \forall t$